# JSON Injection writes unvalidated input into JSON

Tags: java, json

While scanning the code through fortify tool I am getting the below error:

On line 64 of CaApiService.java, the method initializeBearerAuthorizationValue() writes unvalidated input into JSON. This call could allow an attacker to inject arbitrary elements or attributes into the JSON entity.

```
void initializeBearerAuthorizationValue() throws URISyntaxException, BackendException, IOException, ConversionException {
    // Request to CA for Security Token
    CloseableHttpResponse response = requestAuthenticationToken();

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()  != 200) {
        LOGGER.info(IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        throw new BackendException("CaTechnologies configuration is not configured correctly");
    }

    // Parse response and return Bearer string to be used in all subsequent requests
    String theString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map map = mapper.readValue(theString, Map.class);

    bearerAuthorizationValue = "Bearer " + Base64.encodeBase64String(String.format("{\"tkn\":\"%s\",\"all\":true}",
            map.get("tkn")).getBytes());
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is line 64? Can you point the line clearly?

Comment: Map map = mapper.readValue(theString, Map.class); but i think this is coz of get method above that  in String theString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());